# Check and add based of the first 4 digits of each element in a list in Python

Tags: python

I've been struggling with this for the last 3 hours. I need to make a code that, using only lists:

1. Takes the input of various IDs and turns them into lists. To do that I made this code:

   ```
   def getID():
       id = input("Enter the IDs separated by a space: ")
       idlist = id.split()
       print (get2015(idlist))
       return ""
   ```
2. After getting the input, check from what year they are. The Ids have the following format (20(15-22)xxxxxx, for example, 2015123456, where the first four digits indicate on what year the person was born. Then, add how many people was born in that year. This is what I tried for the year 2015 but isn't working.

   ```
   def get(id):

       sum= 0
       for x in id[:3]:
           if x == "2015":
               sum+= 1
   return sum
   ```

An example of the output I need would be:

```
Input: 

2015000000, 2016000000, 2015000011

Output:

Born in 2015: 2
Born in 2016 : 1
```

How could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to use a dictionary.

```
def getID():
    id = input("Enter the IDs separated by a space: ")
    idlist = id.split(", ") #In your input example you separate them by comma
    for id in idlist:
        addBirth(id[:4])
    
    print(birthData)

birthData = {} #Create an empty dictionary
def addBirth(year):
    #Check if key exists
    if year in birthData:
        birthData[year] += 1
    else: 
        #If the key wasn't present create a new key and initialise it to 1
        birthData[year] = 1
```

`getID()` with the input `2015000000, 2016000000, 2015000011` outputs the following:

```
{'2015': 2, '2016': 1}
```

However, because you can't use dictionaries, you can use list indices.

```
startYear = 2015
endYear = 2022

yearCount = endYear - startYear

#Create a list with as many items as years, all initialised to 0
birthData = [0]*yearCount 

def addBirth(year):
    birthData[int(year) - startYear] += 1
```

With the same input, it outputs:

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In order to print the data like you suggested (only for the list version):

```
def printBirthData(birthData):
    #For each year in the year range (2015 - 2022)
    for year in range(yearCount):
        #Only if there has been at least 1 birth that year
        if birthData[year] != 0:
            #Using f strings format the year and the year's data
            print(f"Born in {startYear + year}: {birthData[year]}")
```

Outputs:

```
Born in 2015: 2
Born in 2016: 1
```

Comment: this is working for me, but I need to ask, what does birthData = {} do?

Comment: {} creates an empty dictionary. It's the same as dict()

Comment: I've added some comments with explanations :)

Comment: It works great, but is there a way to print them in a format list, for example Born in 2015: x, Born in 2016: x ?

Comment: Done, I've added it

Comment: You just saved me and my group, we had no clue on how to do this using only lists. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more question hehe, is there a way to put startYear = 2015
endYear = 2022 yearCount = endYear - startYear and birthData = [0]*yearCount inside the functions? Theoretically I can't have anything outside of them

Comment: Yes. I'd put the 3 of them inside of getID. Keep in mind that if you do that, when you call getID, you'll get a new variable created, so you'll have lost the stuff you added to birthData in the last call, because the variable belongs to the function and when you exit it, it gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Counter` here:

```py
from collections import Counter
inp = ["2015000000", "2016000000", "2015000011"]
print(Counter([x[:4] for x in inp]))  # Counter({'2015': 2, '2016': 1})
```

Comment: Is  there a way to do it using only lists of regex? that's the only things I can use sadly

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a separate dictionary of years, loop over the entries in your list of IDs, and check if the first four digits in it correspond to a year in the dictionary. If yes, increase its value in the dictionary by one. If not, add it as a new key to the dictionary with value one:

```
years = dict()
for id in idlist:
    year = id[:4]
    if year in years.keys():
        years[year] += 1
    else:
        years[year] = 1
```

Comment: could I create a list instead of dictionary? I can't use those

Comment: Well, you want to keep track of two pieces of information: A given year, and the count of occurrences of that year among your IDs. These two pieces of information belong together, and that's exactly what dictionaries in Python are made for. If your assignment prohibits you from using dictionaries, then I'm sure there's a workaround (e.g. two lists, one for years and one for counts, and the two are linked together by having the same indices for the year and the corresponding count). But that would be unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: Yep, it is unnecessarily complicated, but sadly that's what we're asked to do. The assignment tilte is "Iterative lists", but 'll try with someone's suggestion of using a list to store the years.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
the list years will store from 2015 to 2022 count.

> example: years[0] is for 2015

```
fun getSum(idList):
    years = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for id in idList :
        year = int(id[:4])
        years[year-2015] += 1
    return years

idList = ['201567899','202267868']
years = getSum(idList)
for i in range(len(years)):
    print('Born in {} : {}'.format(i+2015,years[i]))
```

Comment: I'll try this. Would you mind telling me where in the code would you put it?

Comment: This will create a list with sum for all the years from 2015 to 2022 when passes with list of Id's. You can create a function which will return the list with sum of years and print each element of the list by adding 2015 to the index of list.

Comment: alright, I will try this! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated the answer with usage too.